# Does the default ArcGIS JavaScript API (v4) popup support related records?

Tags: javascript, api, popup, esri

I'm not sure if i'm overlooking things or this is not yet supported, but i'm curious if the default JavaScript API (v4) popup supports related records.

I have the following situation:

- Hosted feature service on ArcGIS Online. In it three sublayers
  (trees, roads and vegetation). Each of the sublayers has a related
  table in which i store quality-inspection records (quality level,
  date of inspection and attachment-option). The relation is 1-m.
- Hosted feature service is added to a webmap which is also stored on
  AGO.
- In my custom front-end i created a mapView which loads the
  entire webmap at once (rather than adding all layer individually) Map
  draws perfectly and the popup works, but does not show the related
  records. Related records are however visible and editable in
  collector, explorer and via webappbuilder (see screenshot).

[Example in jsapi v4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4foA.png)

[Example in webappbuilder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx9gX.png)

What i'm looking for is the option to add the functionality regarding the related records in the second screenshot to the situation in the first screenshot.

My exact question is twofold:

- Is this supported by default and if yes, how do i turn it on?
- If this is not a default option, how would one go about and custom create this functionality? (as in which elements are needed)

Answer (score 0):

Check out these links, I hope they help you:

[Multiple popup elements](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/popup-multipleelements/index.html)
[Example - Sandbox](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=popup-multipleelements)